# Win10 Mail App Exchange connected - remote wipe capabilities?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, remote-control, windows-10-mail-app

I would like to connect an office exchange mail account to Windows 10 mail app on my home desktop. Can a company admin remotely wipe parts of my hard drive or worse case remotely format all my non OS drives?

I ask this as I understand that the company would probably like to be able to wipe any company data such as work emails (which is normal and OK) should I leave the company. However remotely wiping any personal data is unacceptable to me - Android phone does allow company admin to remotely wipe phone - so I won't be having work email synced to phone. Period. As such I need to know what exactly an admin can do should I connect work Exchange to Windows 10 mail App on desktop PC.

Are there any recommended mitigation measures to keep personal data safe whilst allowing company to delete work data (preferably avoiding draconian measures like virtual machines! Eg: Creating a work only partition?)?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are working from home then the company should either provide a laptop for you to use or allow you to VPN into the company network and work there.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, it's recommended to sync your work emails via Outlook client other than Mail APP on Windows 10, or you just access and handle emails in OWA on your own desktop.

It's high risk that your computer is reset and most data were lost unexpectedly. As Microsoft states:

*In addition to resetting the mobile phone to factory default condition, a remote device wipe also deletes any data on any storage card that's inserted in the mobile phone. If you're performing a remote device wipe on a mobile phone in your possession and want to keep the data on the storage card, remove the storage card before you initiate the remote device wipe.*

See:https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124591(v=exchg.141).aspx